# Circular Reveal Effect like WhatsApp in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

in [this blog](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/circular-reveal-effect-like-whatsapp-in-android/) we can make simple reveal effect for some layout in android java familiar. my question about is any library on implementation like with this animation?

[image]

for example:

```
android.view.ViewAnimationUtils
   Animator anim = android.view.ViewAnimationUtils
      .createCircularReveal(mRevealView, cx, cy, 0, radius);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved by using this [library](https://github.com/qwert2603/circular_reveal_animation)

```
CircularRevealAnimation(
    child: Image.asset('assets/ocv.jpg'),
    animation: animation,
    center: Offset(130, 100),
),
```